# Dismiss a nib an pop to a view controller in a tab bar controller

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, xib

My app it's embedded in a tab bar controller, but I'm using a nib in which I'm doing some operation.
At the end of this operation I've to pop to a view controller in my tab bar controller. I tried to use this code (suggested by an another user on here):

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:<#(NSUInteger)#>];
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

but it doesn't do anything. I guessed i should use this instructions:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```

but I've to put something in the `completion`, I don't know how to do that, can you help me?

**Update:**
I will show you my storyboard so you can understand what I'm trying to explain:

[image]

also in "Product View Controller", when I press on a button (I design the button by code) it shows me this file XIB:

[image]

In this view there's a button (usually it's hidden), when I press on this button it will add the product I'm looking to a remote cart. After the adding this product to the remote cart, I will pop to the "Carriage View Controller". When I pop to the "Carriage View Controller" I should pass them some data of my cart.
So my app has this tab view:

- Home View Controller: the main view controller, loaded when the app is started
- Category View Controller: it's a table view controller in which I'm displaying the category of products in my store
- Carriage View Controller: a controller in which I will display the data of my cart
- Info View Controller: a controller in which I display information about the app

From the "Category View Controller" with a segue I pop a View Controller in which I display by a custom view the products. When I press on one of this products it calls a the xib file I posted before file in which there are the details of the product selected before.
I hope you understand better what I'm trying to do.

**CODE:**

Here's the code to display the xib I posted:

```
- (void)collectionView:(PSCollectionView *)collectionView didSelectCell:(PSCollectionViewCell *)cell atIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    int productID = (int)index;
    productID = productID + 1;
    if (IS_IPHONE_5) {
        ProductScannedViewController *productScannedVC = [[ProductScannedViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ProductScannedViewControllerRetina4" bundle:nil];
        productScannedVC.idProductScanned = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", productID];
        [productScannedVC setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
        [self presentViewController:productScannedVC animated:YES completion:nil];
    } else {
        ProductScannedViewController *productScannedVC = [[ProductScannedViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ProductScannedViewController" bundle:nil];
        productScannedVC.idProductScanned = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", productID];
        [productScannedVC setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
        [self presentViewController:productScannedVC animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

Comment: "when I press on a button (I design the button by code) it shows me this file XIB" - can you provide the code you use to do that? Also, check the update I made to the answer. It should work.

Comment: I edited my question with the code

Comment: One more thing, where you you want to do the navigation? Inside the ProductScannedViewController? If so, my answer should solve your problem.

Comment: Yeah in ProductScannedViewController, I will try to do when I finished the things I'm doing now :)

Comment: Ok, I'm trying your code, but which view controller is for you the `TestViewController`?

Answer (score 0):

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
       // completion code here
}];
```

You can only use the popToRootViewControllerAnimated method if the view controller is part of that navigation controller's navigation stack.

If you are presenting the view controller like this

```
TestViewController * vc = [[TestViewController alloc] init];
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:^{        
}];
```

And want to do the tab navigation inside I suggest injecting the tab bar as a weak property

```
TestViewController * vc = [[TestViewController alloc] init];
[vc setTabController:self.tabBarController];
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:^{
}];
```

Inside the TestViewController where you want to do the navigation:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
     [tabController setSelectedIndex:0];
}];
```

I tested this code.

Comment: ehm ok... I need the code to pop to a specific view controller in my tab bar controller...

Comment: to change the tab you are viewing use [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:tabIndex];

Comment: If you explain your view controllers hierarchy it will be easier to find the solution.

Comment: I update my question, I hope you can understand better what I'm trying to do